# Как подключиться к процессу по названию окна с помощью PyWinAuto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

Требуется подключиться к уже запущенному процессу. Используя connect разобрался только с подключением пo PID'у, но программа "расплывается" на несколько процессов с одинаковым названием: 3 фоновых и 1 в окне. Нужно вывести PID процесса в окне.

Comment: pgid у этих процессов одинаковый, но pid разный

Comment: @dIm0n Да, я понимаю, что PID разный, но имена-то одинаковые у всех четырёх процессов. Раньше выводил PID c помощью psutil по названию процесса, а щас пытаюсь найти другой способ

Comment: То есть вы хотите подключиться по названию, которое заведомо неуникальное? Так а как вы будете указывать, к чему именно подключаться?

Comment: @dIm0n Именно это я и хочу узнать.

Comment: Падажжите, вы хотите узнать, что вы хотите сделать? :) У вас есть два процесса с одним именем, но разными пидами. К какому из них вы хотите подключиться?

Comment: @dIm0n Так, сначала. У меня есть 4 процесса с одинаковым именем. 3 из них - фоновые, 1 - работает в окне. Мне нужно выводить PID того, что в окне.

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос с помощью кнопки править

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается так (пытаемся подключиться в течение максимум 5 секунд или как окно появится):

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="Window title", timeout=5)
# можно юзать title_re, control_type и всё, что в обычном поиске окна
```

По умолчанию сейчас timeout=0 для коннекта, но в будущем сделаем дефолтные 5 сек, как для обычного поиска окон.

Получить PID процесса (если вдруг зачём ещё это нужно, ведь уже есть объект `app`):

```
print(app.process)
```